# Headphones no sound

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Today I've connected my bluetooth headphones(Ausdom M08) with PC(via bluetooth dongle).

When I open Skype or Discord I hear no sound on youtube, browser and so on. It only works on Skype and Discord - bad sound, not stereo.

I checked in Sounds Options and I have Ausdom M08 Stereo and Ausdom M08 Hands-Free. First one is default device and second one is default communication device.

When I try to force Skype and Discord to use that default device for sound output I hear no sound then, too!

What I tried:
-Disabling Hands Free Telephony, but I lose microphone function then.
-Tried to uninstall drivers and install again. Still the same.
-Disabling enhancements and exclusive controls of devices.

Literally I tried everything I found on internet or that I thought it can be.

Nothing works.

So the question is: How to make my PC output Stereo Sound from my headphones and still to be able to use microphone from it?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you explicitly select the device in Skype, rather than using the "default"?

Comment: When I explicitly select Stereo device in Skype settings I hear nothing then. Both on Skype and all other programs.

I wrote that in the first post, so please read it. Thanks for cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of missing information here: What PC dongle are you using? Which windows version?

From what I can see about the tech specs of [Ausdom M08](http://www.ausdom.com/index.php/audio/detail?ikey=28), it supports few basic profile (HSP/HFP/A2DP/AVRCP). A2DP profile lets you hear stereo audio (Ausdom M08 Stereo). HSP/HFP lets you use the microphone to Skype, but audio is limited to 8K-16K Hz sampling rate (Ausdom M08 Hands-Free). You can't use both Bluetooth profiles at the same time.

So to answer you question: You can't have stereo audio from your headphone while having microphone input.

There are proprietary codec developed by Qualcomm called [aptX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptX), which may support microphone over A2DP. But, you'll have to make sure both transmitter and receiver supports this codec.

Comment: As you have correctly noticed, this question is highly problematic, since it is probably off-topic for SO ([help/on-topic]). Also, if you require clarifications from the asker, they should not appear in your question but as a comment on the question. Please don't answer such questions in the future; the right course of action should be a flag (and possibly a comment).